# Why can't I connect to my NAS?

Tags: networking, lubuntu, automount, nas

I'm new to Ubuntu and installed the newest Lubuntu (old Laptop Toshiba Satellite L350 - 32 bit).

I want to mount my (NAS-)HDD via Fritzbox 7360 (HDD is connected via USB to the Fritzbox). The NAS HDD is in NTFS format.

I tried to follow this wiki

https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Archiv/FritzBox/Automount_USB-Speicher/

I tried way 1 and 3 but I am still not able to have access to the NAS.

I'm sure that I have the correct FRITZ IP
I'm not sure what is meant by "HEIMNETZFREIGABE-DER-FRITZBOX" in way 2 in the file `/etc/fstab`

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: HEIMNETZFREIGABE-DER-FRITZBOX - is the name of the actual Shared folder

Comment: thank you, could you tell me what my shaed folder is and where I find it?

Answer (score 1):

`EIMNETZFREIGABE-DER-FRITZBOX` is the name (and workgroup) you gave the router.

From your link:

[image]

Comment: Ok, but... name or workgroup? //IP-DER-FRITZBOX/HEIMNETZFREIGABE-DER-FRITZBOX/ /media/......  What do I ha ve to add?